# Express.js public folder content only available when logged in

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to access my static image file inside public directory via `http://<IP Address>:3000/image.jpg` and it available only when I am logged in to my server. As soon as I log out I get

GET 404 Not found in Network Tab and instead of page:

```
 Error: Not Found
   at module.exports (<path>/app.js:48:15)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (<path>/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at trim_prefix (<path>/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:13)
   at <path>/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:238:9
   at Function.proto.process_params (<path>/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:313:12)
   at <path>/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:229:12
   at Function.match_layer (<path>/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:296:3)
   at next (<path>/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:190:10)
   at <path>/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:192:16
   at Function.match_layer (<path>/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:296:3)
```

I have `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` in my `app.js` file.

All my routes are working fine and I am getting JSON response when requesting any route when I am logged out and I only get problem with files inside public directory.

I am running my script on server with `forever start -c nodemon bin/www`

I tried moving `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` to the top but same problem.

Does anyone have an idea why public folder is only accessible when I'm logged in to my server?

Comment: What's the order of your middleware and routes, since they are executed in order. If a request hits your route before static and you return a response (404 in your case) then it won't serve the file.

Comment: First 'app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));' and then all the routes.

Comment: is there any other middleware defined before static

Comment: @Naeem Shaikh I've added app.js to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with owner and group of my project folder. I have followed steps as in [this article](http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2011/05/07/install-node-js-and-express-js-nginx-debian-lenny.html) (First Express App part) and everything works fine now.